# Fragment instantiation in kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm new to kotlin and I'd like to create the following code in kotlin:

```
Fragment fragment = null;

switch(id) {
    case R.id.nav_new:
        fragment = new FragAllPosts();
        break;
    case R.id.nav_about:
        fragment = new FragAuthors();
        break;
    case R.id.nav_tags:
        fragment = new FragTags();
        break;
}

if (fragment != null) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

The fragments are very basic and don't contain any parameters yet.
How can I achieve the above in kotlin? Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you're using Android Studio, why don't you simply take that code snippet and paste it into a Kotlin file? The IDE will automatically convert it to correct Kotlin code for you. Or you can write it in a Java file and press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+K to convert the whole file to Kotlin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take the following code snippet as example:

```
var fragment: Fragment? = null
when(id) {
    R.id.nav_new -> fragment = FragAllPosts()
    R.id.nav_about -> fragment = FragAuthors()
    R.id.nav_tags -> fragment = FragTags()
}

if(null != fragment) {
    val ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps!!!

```
var fragment: Fragment? = null
when (id) {
    R.id.nav_new -> fragment = FragAllPosts.newInstance()
    R.id.nav_about -> fragment = FragAuthors.newInstance()
    R.id.nav_tags -> fragment = FragTags.newInstance()
}

// activity use supportFragmentManager
// fragment use childFragmentManager

fragment?.apply {
    supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.content_frame, this)?.commit()
}

// Example class fragment create newInstance function

class FragAllPosts : Fragment() {
    companion object {
        fun newInstance(bundle: Bundle? = null): FragAllPosts = FragAllPosts().apply {
            arguments = bundle
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.